# How to split array dynamically in unique arrays

Tags: c#

I have this mainArray (dynamically generated):

```
    static void Main()
{
    var n = 3;
    var k = 2;
    var a = n * k;
    var mainArray = new int[a];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            mainArray[index] = i;
            index++;
        }
    }

    //=> mainArray=[0,0,1,1,2,2]
    // How to split this array in 3 uniq arrays, like:
    //array1=[0,1]
    //array2=[1,2]
    //array3=[0,2]

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", mainArray));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

mainArray=[0,0,1,1,2,2]

How to split this array in 3 uniq arrays, like:

array1=[0,1]

array2=[1,2]

array3=[0,2]

How can I do it?

Comment: [0,0] [1,1],[2,2] = not uniq; [0,1],[0,1][2,2]=not uniq; , only uniq posibility is the one from my question;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So initially you have a set of `n * k` items of `n` different values where each value is repeated `k` times. And you want to arrange those `n * k` items into `k` sets in such a way that each value in the resulting sets is unique.

You can do it in the following way

```
int[][] res = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => new int[k]).ToArray();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        res[i][j] = (i + j) % n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that all of the arrays have to have different numbers in each array, or that each array must be unique from the others?

If you want to just make arrays with unique numbers, try the following. I'm sure there is a better solution, but I'm fairly certain this may work for your situation.

```
public static int[][] splitUnique(int[] input, int length)
    {
        if (input.Length % length != 0) throw new Exception("Length cannot yield full arrays of length " + length);
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>(input);
        int[][] data = new int[input.Length / length][];
        int dataIndex = 0;
        while (numbers.Count != 0)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[length];
            int tempIndex = 0;
            foreach (int num in numbers)
            {
                if (!temp.Contains(num))
                {
                    temp[tempIndex] = num;
                    tempIndex++;
                }
                if (tempIndex >= length)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach (int num in temp)
            {
                numbers.Remove(num);
            }
            data[dataIndex] = temp;
            dataIndex++;
        }
        return data;
    }
```